Deploying an External Client App
We are looking into migrating our connected apps to external client apps. So far so good, the migration and configuration are easy enough, but when trying to deploy an external client app, it's not exactly what I was expecting.
I saw that the metadata file is very different from the regular connected apps. From my understanding, what happens is that you specify the org id and the API name of the app and then the deployment should create an app that's identical to the one with the mentioned API name, from the mentioned org.
However, that's not happening. When deploying, I do get an app with the same name and a few other fields that were explicitly mentioned in the metadata file but it's not at all identical with the one I originally developed. The app policies and the OAuth settings are just not there.
I was wondering if anyone else worked with this and how you managed to deploy. Thanks!

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.meta_external_client_apps_creation.htm&type=5
